# Recursive SQL Query - Previous Id

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have following table:

```
| ID | TYPE  | NAME | PREV_ID |
===============================
| 1  | E     | X1   | 1       |
-------------------------------
| 2  | M     | X2   | 1       |
-------------------------------
| 3  | M     | X2   | 2       |
-------------------------------
| 4  | G     | X3   | 3       |
-------------------------------
```

So Prev_Id references on Id of the same table. Starting with ID 4 I need the complete "path" down to ID 1. There might be several entries of type "m" between the starting "E" and the final "C", so the list might be longer or even shorter.
Is it possible to get the complete chain of connected items with one query?

Comment: I am using Oracle.

Comment: Asked and answered many times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+recursive-query or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+connect-by

Comment: Oracle also supports Sql standard CTE as well now. A lot of  hierarchy CTE examples can be found at SE.

Answer (score 2):

It is typical hierarchical query, the only thing you have to notice is that for `id` = 1 `prev_id` is also 1, what causes infinite loop and error `ORA-01436`, so you have to add `nocycle` in `connect by` query or condition in CTE version.

Solution 1:

```
select t.*, connect_by_root(id)||sys_connect_by_path(prev_id, '=>') path
  from t 
  connect by nocycle id = prior prev_id
  start with id = 4
```

Solution 2 (Oracle 11g or later):

```
with cte(id, type, name, prev_id, path) as (
    select t.*, id||'=>'||prev_id from t where id = 4
    union all
    select t.id, t.type, t.name, t.prev_id, cte.path||'=>'||t.prev_id 
      from t join cte on t.id = cte.prev_id
      where t.id <> t.prev_id )
select * from cte
```

Output and [demo](http://rextester.com/ULKSC8767) for both queries:

```
    ID TYPE NAME    PREV_ID PATH
------ ---- ---- ---------- ---------------
     4 G    X3            3 4=>3
     3 M    X2            2 4=>3=>2
     2 M    X2            1 4=>3=>2=>1
```